# Function to remove all characters and special symbols in cell of Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a lot of data in Google Sheets.
I need some fuction to extract numbers only from:

```
Some_Text-is_Here_12345678_FH-1
87654321-Some-Text_is_Here-FH-2 
FH-3-00054321_Some_Text-is_Here
```

to new cells:

```
12345678
87654321
00054321
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\d{8})")
```

For German locale change `,` to `;`.

Comment: it looks good, but there is an Error in Google Sheets (#Error! syntaxis error in the formula)

Comment: Nice! Thank you! But some cells contain only digit like 12345678... Now there is an Error #VALUE! Could you change REGEXEXTRACT please?